# Is using List<Byte> not good idea?

Tags: java, c++, iterator

I need to re-write some C++ code in Java that I wrote years ago.

In C++, I used a `std::vector<unsigned char> buffer` to implement a buffer which I would retrieve from a socket connection.

With this buffer I do all kinds of operations:

- Have an iterator to buffer element and advance it as required.
- Search it for certain tokens.
- Get a range of byte elements (sub-buffer) from buffer using indexes / iterators.

Based on these requirements, I could use `ArrayList<Byte>` and have a custom iterator-like class to keep track of current element and work using indexes.

In what ways will be in-efficient to use `List<Byte>`?

Somewhere else I have seen `ByteBuffer` being recommended but my requirements don't call for it.

Perhaps because I need indexes, searches to perform, etc. and my buffer won't change or be modified once created.

All I need is to read the buffer and perform above operations.

Should I better just have a wrapper around `byte[]` with my own iterator/pointer class?

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't require a custom iterator-like class, since there is one and you get it with `iterator()` (or you could use `stream()` in Java 8+). Prefer `ArrayList` if you don't know the buffer size ahead of time, `ByteBuffer` is faster and more efficient (but requires you know the size).

Comment: The problem is I cannot advance the iterator to 10 to 20 steps forward (using a loop seems bad) which is why I thought I could just write a custom one using just indexes. Since I am not modifying the buffer at all and require searching to be done, so `ByteBuffer` seems unnecessary as well.

Comment: No, seriously, use `ByteBuffer`.  It doesn't matter what operations you need, an `ArrayList<Byte>` will just be embarrassingly inefficient.  Modifications, searches, whatever, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I am guessing because it holds references to `Byte` objects which are spread randomly over the heap compared to `ByteBuffer` which holds contiguous bytes?

Comment: They're probably not spread _randomly,_ but any extra heap indirections are way more cost than you need for anything like this.

Comment: I appreciate the accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on your requirements. The huge problem with `List<Byte>` is the fact that you are using [`Byte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) objects rather than primitive `byte` values!

Not only does that affect memory consumption, it also means that there *might* be a lot of [boxing/unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) going on. 
That *may* cause a lot of objects to be generated<sup>†</sup> - leading to constant churn for the garbage collector.

So if you intend to do intensive computations, or you are working massive amounts of data, then the [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class has various performance advantages here.

---

<sup>† from [Java Language Specification §5.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)</sup>

> <sup>The rule above is a pragmatic compromise, requiring that certain common values always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. **The implementation may cache these, lazily or eagerly**.</sup>

Comment: I am considering to have just a wrapper around `byte[]` with my own iterator since I am not modifying the buffer, just retrieving and searching through it. In case I missed, can you search `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: @cpx Yes, you can set the position you want to start reading/writing via [`ByteBuffer#position(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position-int-).

Answer (score 0):

`List` is not a class, it's an interface, so you need to supply an actual class behind it, to provide an implementation.  You can use a `List<Byte>` variable on your code, to hide the implementation details of the actual class you are using, but if you need it behave as an array sometimes, and as a List others (whit iterators and such), then you need not to abandon the `ArrayList<Byte>` class and continue using it, to be able to use the index and list behaviours together.  If you switch to a `List<Byte>`, finally you will end doing unnecessary casts to access the array features of `ArrayList`, and these will consume cpu, checking that the proper class is being cast.  And you'll blur the code.  Also, you have alternatives in `ByteBuffer` or `CharBuffer`, as suggested by other responses.  But beware that these class are `abstract`, so you'll have to implement part of them, before being able to use.

Comment: "*But beware that these class are abstract, so you'll have to implement part of them, before being able to use*" - [Not at all](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate-int-): `ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);`